# I have a question about precedence rules in C

Tags: c, function, operator-precedence, rules

In the following function:

```
int fun(int *k) {
    *k += 4;
    return 3 * (*k) - 1;
}

void main() {
    int i = 10, j = 10, sum1, sum2;
    sum1 = (i / 2) + fun(&i);
    sum2 = fun(&j) + (j / 2);
}
```

You'd get sum 1 to equal 46, and sum 2 to equal 48. How would the function run if there were no precedence rules?

How drastically difference would things run without consistent precedence rules?

Comment: This is undefined behavior. `fun(&i)` has side effect on `i`, but you access it in the same statement before sequence point.

Comment: To bypass the undefined behavior, let's pretend you wrote `sum1 = (i / 2) + 10;`. If there were no precedence rules (but presumably there would still be left-to-right associativity for binary operators and grouping of sub-expressions by parentheses), `sum1 = (i / 2) + 10;` would be evaluated as `(sum1 = (i / 2)) + 10;`.

Comment: operator precedence is like with grammar in natural language allowing to decide in a sentence who is the subject and who is the additional subject. Without precedence is like without grammar, and in that case you are not able to understand that remark ;-)

Comment: @bruno Master Yoda agree do not.

Comment: @EugeneSh. may the precedence rules be with us ;-)

Comment: "You'd get sum 1 to equal 46, and sum 2 to equal 48" -- you *might*.  It is very important to understand that the C language in no way guarantees that.  Others have observed that the behavior is in fact undefined, but I want to press home the point that even if you happen to observe a certain result for those two computations, that in no way makes those results correct or predictable in any general sense.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: No, the behavior is not undefined. There are sequence points between the evaluation of the function arguments and the call of the function and after each full expression in the function, including the return. The behavior is unspecified in that the order of evaluation between `i/2` and `fun(&x)` is not determined, but it is not undefined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, given that the computations of subexpressions `i/2` and `fun(&i)` are unsequenced relative to each other, as you affirm, and that the latter has a side effect on the value of `i`, I would be inclined to say that paragraph 6.5/2 applies: "If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @JohnBollinger: This has been discussed previously and is established. See C 2018 5.1.2.3 3, “… Evaluations A and B are *indeterminately sequenced* when A is sequenced either before or after B, but it is unspecified which…” There is more in that paragraph and the note that makes it clear that if a sequence point is known to be between A and B, then they are indeterminately sequenced and their parts cannot interleave regardless of which order is chosen for them, whereas, without a sequence point (or other ordering constraint), they are unsequenced and their parts can interleave.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I know the difference between unsequenced and indeterminately sequenced.  I also know that, in general, the evaluations of subexpressions are *un*sequenced relative to each other, per 6.5/3.  But you are right all the same. I did not previously appreciate the part of 6.5.2.2/10, that provides a special case for the sequencing of function-call subexpressions (entirely separate from and independent of the sequence points it also specifies, though they too are relevent here).

Comment: It does not matter much whether the code is undefined, unspecified or well-defined  - It's just bad, and anyone who writes such should be fired or awarded F-, as appropriate:(

Answer (score 0):

The precedence rules tell us how an expression is **structured**, not how it is **evaluated**. In `sum1 = (i / 2) + fun(&i);`, the rules tell us things including:

- `i / 2` is grouped together because it is in parentheses; it cannot form, for example, `(sum1 = i) / 2 + fun(&i);`.
- `(i / 2)` and `fun(&i)` are grouped together because `+` has higher precedence than `=`, making `sum1 = ((i / 2) + fun(&i);` rather than `(sum1 = (i / 2)) + fun(&i);`.

The precedence rules do not tell us whether `i / 2` or `fun(&i)` is evaluated first. In fact, no rules in the C standard specify whether `i / 2` or `fun(&i)` is evaluated first. The compiler may choose.

If `i / 2` is evaluated first, the result will be `10 / 2 + 41` and then `5 + 41` and finally `46`. if `fun(&i)` is evaluated first, the result will be `14 / 2 + 41` and then `7 + 41` and finally `48`. Your compiler chose the former. It could have chosen the latter.

> How would the function run if there were no precedence rules?

If there were no rules, we would not know how the function would be executed. The rules are what tell us how it will be executed.

Some comments assert that the behavior of this program is undefined. That is incorrect. This misunderstanding comes from C 2018 6.5 2, which says:

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined…

In your code, `i / 2` uses `i` and `fun(&i)` contains a “side effect” on `i` (changing its value via an assignment). If these were unsequenced, the behavior would be undefined. However, there is a sequence point after evaluating the argument to `fun` and before calling it, and there are sequence points after each full expression in `fun`, including its `return` statement. Thus, there is some sequencing of the uses of `i` and the side effects on it. This sequencing is incompletely determined by the rules of the C standard, but it is, as defined by the standard, indeterminately sequenced, not unsequenced.

Comment: Following up on the comments on the question, then, your emphasis on the sequence points is misplaced.  They do ensure that the side effect on `i` is sequenced before the computation of the function return value, which is necessary, but the only thing that makes the evaluations of `i / 2` and `fun(&i)` (and the latter's side effects) indeterminately sequenced with respect to each other, instead of unsequenced, is the special-case provision of 6.5.2.10 that gives that special property to function-call subexpressions.  There are similar cases that are not rescued by any of that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: The answer contains no emphasis on sequence points. That information is after the main points and is not bolded or otherwise specially marked. I would not have included it except to correct the misinformation in the comments. The question is not about sequence points, and I have no intent to go further into the subject than needed to correct the erroneous comments.