# () has the highest priority, why is it short-circuited？

Tags: c, operators, short-circuiting, logical-and

() has the highest priority, why is it short-circuited？

```
int a = 1, b = 0;
(--a)&&(b++);
```

Why is (b++) still short-circuited?

Comment: You're getting False at your condition? I think it's right since `b` is evaluated (0) then incremented.

Comment: Why would parenthesis change the short circuit?

Comment: Pioriority does not affect directly  an order of computation. It only impact the grammar tree

Comment: [Operator precedence tells us how an expression is structured, not how it is evaluated.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61368867/298225)

Answer (score 4):

The expression (--a) uses the prefix operator and evaluates to 0.  This is false and the 2nd expression is not evaluated due to short-circuit as you noted.

Answer (score 4):

I don't find the term "short-circuit" particularly helpful.

It is better to say that `&&` and `||` have *left-to-right order of evaluation*. The C standard (6.5.13) actually explains this well:

> the && operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation ...
> If the first operand compares equal to 0, the second
> operand is not evaluated.

And that's it. The left operand `--a` evaluates to 0.

---

[What is the difference between operator precedence and order of evaluation?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/278172)

In this case, all that matters is order of evaluation. Operator precedence only guarantees that the expression is parsed as expected - which operands that "glue" to which operator.

Answer (score 1):

To understand consider the following expression

```
a * b + c * d
```

If to assume that the operands of the operator `+` are evaluated from left to right then at first the expression a * b will be evaluated and then the expression c * d.

The assumption relative to the order of evaluations of operands of the operator + is not valid. But it is valid for the operator &&.

So left operand of the expression

```
(--a)&&(b++);
```

is evaluated first. And if its value is not equal to 0 then the second operand is evaluated.

From the C Standard (6.5.13 Logical AND operator)

> 4 **Unlike the bitwise binary & operator, the && operator guarantees
> left-to-right evaluation;** if the second operand is evaluated, there
> is a sequence point between the evaluations of the first and second
> operands. If the first operand compares equal to 0, the second operand
> is not evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that you can override operator precedence using parenthesis `()`.

For example, the expression

`a && b || c`

is equivalent to

`(a && b) || c`,

because `&&` has a higher precedence than `||`. You can override this precedence by changing it to

`a && (b || c)`

so that now the `||` has precedence over `&&`.

However, operator procedence doesn't change the behavior of the individual operators. In particular, both operators will still use short-circuiting. So, even if `||` has higher precedence than `&&`, the `&&` operator will still evaluate its left-hand operand before its right-hand operand.

In both of my examples above, the `&&` operator will still evalulate `a` before evaluating `b` or `(b || c)`. Operator precedence will only affect whether the right-hand operand of the `&&` operator is the expression `b` or `(b || c)`.

Therefore, in your example, by writing `(--a)&&(b++)` instead of `--a&&b++`, you are merely ensuring that the `--` and `++` operators have precedence over the `&&` operator. This is not necessary, because he C language specifies that these operators already have precedence.

In the hypothetical scenario that the C language had instead specified that the `&&` operator had precedence over the `--` and `++` operators, then the expression `--a&&b++` would be interpreted as `--(a&&b)++`, and it would be necessary to write `(--a)&&(b++)` to prevent this interpretation. But this is not the case.